# Connection to PostgreSql database with Android Kotlin

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

I am new to android development. I am developing an android application for my workplace. Can we connect directly to postgreSQL database without API using kotlin language on Android? If yes, how?. Also, can someone provide me a link to find similar results sourcebook?

I am waiting for your answers

Comment: why would you expose your database to a such fragile architeture?

Comment: Because I need this urgently for now

Comment: You won't spend a lot of time developing an api for that. You don't need to make it complex at the beging

Comment: I'm already developing an api, if you read carefully I stated that it is urgent.

Comment: https://medium.com/cyber-explorer/how-to-connect-an-android-project-to-a-postgresql-database-663cb0f5ba19